# Starting session variable with name of subdirectory

Tags: php, directory, session-variables

Say a user goes directly to the url mainDir.com/subDir. The sub directory is the name of a page that they created, and I'm trying to find a way to set that name into a session variable. For example, `$_SESSION['page'] = 'name_of_subDir';` If a user were to click a link to get to mainDir.com/subDir, I could first send them to mainDir.com/?page=foo, then `$_GET['page']`, store that into `$_SESSION['page']`, and redirect them to mainDir.com/subDir with the session being set, but the issue being that I can't always send a user to mainDir.com/?page=foo if they just go straight to the main url mainDir.com/subDir by typing it in the address bar. What might be some ways to fix this issue?

Comment: `mainDir.com/subDir` can check whether the session variable is set. If not, it redirects to the main page.

Comment: Or use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI`]` to find out the name of the directory and see if it subDir ... if it is set the session value as needed.